# Generate a unique page link that can be bookmarked using javascript and php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bookmarks

On this website http://berm.tv I am showing a series of videos that use javascript and php to load new content every time a forward and back arrow are pressed.

Here is the relevant javascript:

```
$('#content').load("pagination.php?page=1", function() {
    sizeVideo();
});
```

In PHP, I get the ?page= variable and use that to load the appropriate content.

Is it possible to bookmark a specific page. For example. ?page=3?

Comment: One minute you want new content on loaded a new page. The next you want to be able to bookmark that content. I am confused

Comment: Sorry if I described it poorly. I want to be able to bookmark any page on the site but the ?page= part of the URL doesn't actually show up when new content is loaded so I am unable to bookmark it.

Comment: Reconfigure the web server so that the ?page bit can be `/.../1` The `1` can be passed to the application. This depends on the server

Comment: Would this be in an .htaccess file? I'm googling around trying to find something similar.